# Xampp : server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Tags: apache, xampp

I had both apache and mysql ok and running in xampp control panel. But then when i tried to load one of my php pages i was getting a fatal error :

```
Call to undefined function mysql_connect().
```

Upon searching about this error i came across some answers. Mostly people suggested in the file php.ini to change extension_dir = "./" to extension_dir = "C:\php\ext" and uncomment the line ;extension=php_mysql.dll.

I tried that, but now when i try to restart apache i get

```
error:apache shutdown unexpectedly
```

and in the logs it shows:

```
server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

Does anybody know what i am suppose to do next? I have spent hours trying to solve this problem but to no avail. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: "server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name" is about the SSL setup in Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I got the problem solved!
Because you installed the XAMPP with the PHP 7+ in it instead of PHP 5+
I am new to php as well.  The crash is due to PHP 7 is not supporting mysql anymore.

https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

You will aware that there are three different version of PHP.

To confirm, you can create a page called checking.php (the name is not important)
Just write the phpinfo() code inside.

```
<?php
phpinfo() 
?>
```

You can check all the details about your php version!

~~~~~~~~~~
Not an answer below 
~~~~~~~~~~
 That's was just my puzzle a day before.
I am sorry that I am not providing solution but I am saying that I am encountering the exact same thing!
It is very puzzling.

in the php.ini file

;extension=php_mysql.dll

We saw the above line such that the mysql function is not working.

remove the ;

then failed to start with the same error.

[Fri Jan 22 16:18:04.964120 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1188:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:XXXX:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 22 16:18:05.014120 2016] [core:warn] [pid 1188:tid 384] AH00098: pid file D:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri Jan 22 16:18:05.104120 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1188:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:XXXX:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: How is MySQL remotely connected?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem (server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name. I don't know what the root cause is but I was able to fix it with `XAMPP version 5.6-30`. Before that, I tried other versions like `7` and `1.7-4` with no success. That good version is available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/).