# XAMPP: "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly" Not Skype

Tags: php, apache, xampp

My XAMPP Apache shut down randomly after working correctly a few times.

It's a fresh install of XAMPP after de-installing the older version.

I have no Skype installed and have no clue why Apache suddenly started giving me this problem.

Here's my error log:

```
[Thu Aug 17 18:17:29.635739 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 10468:tid 548] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 17 18:17:29.784258 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 10468:tid 548] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 17 18:17:29.882271 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10468:tid 548] AH00455: Apache/2.4.26 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 17 18:17:29.882271 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10468:tid 548] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jun 15 2017 12:39:41
[Thu Aug 17 18:17:29.882271 2017] [core:notice] [pid 10468:tid 548] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Aug 17 18:17:29.906774 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10468:tid 548] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8840
[Thu Aug 17 18:17:30.771384 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 8840:tid 584] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 17 18:17:30.900902 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 8840:tid 584] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 17 18:17:30.932905 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8840:tid 584] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Aug 17 18:18:11.749117 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 4576:tid 204] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 17 18:18:11.895636 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 4576:tid 204] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 17 18:18:11.929640 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4576:tid 204] AH00455: Apache/2.4.26 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 17 18:18:11.929640 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4576:tid 204] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jun 15 2017 12:39:41
[Thu Aug 17 18:18:11.929640 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4576:tid 204] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Aug 17 18:18:11.946142 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4576:tid 204] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9284
[Thu Aug 17 18:18:12.907264 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 9284:tid 556] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 17 18:18:13.041782 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 9284:tid 556] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Aug 17 18:18:13.076286 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9284:tid 556] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Fri Aug 18 09:43:54.467476 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 10840:tid 704] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Aug 18 09:43:54.512482 2017] [core:warn] [pid 10840:tid 704] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri Aug 18 09:43:54.616495 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 10840:tid 704] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Aug 18 09:43:55.080056 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10840:tid 704] AH00455: Apache/2.4.26 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Aug 18 09:43:55.080056 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10840:tid 704] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jun 15 2017 12:39:41
[Fri Aug 18 09:43:55.080056 2017] [core:notice] [pid 10840:tid 704] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Aug 18 09:43:55.099557 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10840:tid 704] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7628
[Fri Aug 18 09:43:56.123688 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 7628:tid 600] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Aug 18 09:43:56.266206 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 7628:tid 600] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Aug 18 09:43:56.302211 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7628:tid 600] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: Does XAMPP normally report certificate errors after a fresh install?

Comment: To be honest I have no clue. It's a clean install on a pretty old machine though, about ten years old.

What could this mean? (I'm very new to all of this)

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment I will try to guess what could be the problem. You say it is a clean instalation, **try running xampp-control.exe as administrator**
or maybe this will help? [XAMPP PHP version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643156/xampp-server-certificate-does-not-include-an-id-which-matches-the-server-name)

Comment: It was running as administrator. But I found a way to get it to work. After some googling I noticed that the Windows "World Wide We Publishing-Service" interfered with XAMPP's Apache. So I ran the CMD command "net stop was /y" and Apache stopped giving me problems.

Thanks for your help nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by running the "net stop was /y" command in CMD.

Apparently some windows services (World Wide Web Publishing service, Net.Msmq Listener Adapter service, and Windows Process Activation service) interfered with XAMPP's Apache.